# Laravel 5.1: custom validation class

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1, custom-validators

I made this custom validation class, `CustomValidator.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidator extends Validator{

    public function validateRequiredWithOneOf($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $data = $this->getData();
        foreach ($parameters as $p) {
            if ( array_get($data,$p) != null) {return true;}
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function replaceRequiredWithOneOf($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
    {
        return $this->replaceRequiredWith($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters);
    }
}
```

which I call in my `CustomRequest.php`

```
'input_field' => 'required_with_one_of:first,second,third',
```

If the attribute `input_field` is selected, then at least one of the parameter fields (`first`,`second`,`third`) must be selected also.

If I define custom validation inside of `boot()` method of `AppServiceProvider.php` it all works but not if I create this CustomValidator class and delete the code from `AppServiceProvider.php`.

This doesn't surprise me since I'm calling `Validator` and not `CustomValidator` in my `CustomRequest` class.

My `CustomRequest` class extends `Request` classs which extends `FormRequest` class in which `Validator` is mentioned in many places. I really don't know where to start here.
If required I can c/p the `FormRequest` class here.

Can anybody help me work this one out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating `CustomValidator` just call `resolver` method in the `boot()` method:

```
\Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

Also, calling it inside of `CustomRequest` does not make differece. Should works without problems.

Comment: Thanks, is that a typo ` \ ` in front of `Validator::...` or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it is not. Using `\ ` avoid namespace conflict, because by default php will think that `Validator` is a class declared under `App` namespace. Remeber that `Validator` is not a class, but a facade.

Comment: I don't really understand what "avoid namespace conflict" means, but I'll give you "one up" because you gave me something to Google for.